# find elements by class whose id contains a substring and change the style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, substring

I have a set of elements with a style (stripe) and I need to find, in this set, those elements whose id contains a substring (element_A59) and this subset I need to change the style (stripe_new) and the others remove their style (stripe).

I used this jquery sentence, but it didn't work:

```
$('.stripe').find("td[id*=element_A59]").removeClass('stripe').addClass('stripe_new');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather use attribute contains selector along with class selector to get the desired elements:

```
$('td[id*=element_A59].stripe').removeClass('stripe').addClass('stripe_new');
```

Comment: I used this because I found it more accurate

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your markup (for example is `.stripe` defined on the `td` itslef?), it's difficult to answer your question.

`find()` will try to locate child elements. It looks like you're actually looking for the IDs of the matched elements.

You should probably use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
$('.stripe').filter('[id*="element_A59"]').removeClass('stripe').addClass('stripe_new');
```

Here's what `filter()` does:

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match
>   the selector or pass the function's test.

So essentially, by passing the substring selector to `filter()`, the matched `td.stripe` elements will be reduced to those whose ID attribute contains `element_A59`.